# Ubuntu mount point does not exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I am trying to fix a broken Ubuntu upgrade, and so I am following the steps here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure

And when I get to step number 4 `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`, I get the following error:

> mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist

Running this:

```
sudo fdisk -l

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 250068991 249567234  119G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 250068991 249567232  119G 8e Linux LVM
```

Then running this:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1

fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/dev/sda1: clean, 312/62248 files, 107999/248832 blocks
```

Why can I not mount this?

Comment: You imply that step 3 was OK, so you _have_ mounted `/dev/sda1`. The error is telling you that there is no `/dev` folder within this boot file system. You should enter `ls /mnt/`to see what _is_ on that file system, if anything. You probably ought to dismount the boot disc again and do a file system check with `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`.

Comment: Am I mounting the right thing? When I cd to the directory, it contains: `grub/`, `lost+found/` and other files but no other folders. It then looks like it mounts something else (with my users home directory and all the files I installed before the issue) with it, which has those folders...

Comment: `/dev/sda1` looks to be the boot and `/dev/sda2` is my file system. So is this correct? when I try to mount `/dev/sda2` I get an error saying it isn't a valid `NTFS`

Comment: I don't have a `/grub/` directory in any of my dual-boot file systems: my only `grub/` directory is in `/boot/`. Your `fdisk` listing shows that `/dev/sda2` is an extended partition, which cannot be mounted: it is there to hold other partitions, so your live system is in `/dev/sda5`. You will get a clearer view of your partition structure by running `disks` or `gparted`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it.

```
sudo lvdisplay

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
```

I then was able to do this:

```
sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /mnt
```

I was then able to finish the rest of the steps.